# ValueError: too many values to unpack when using itertuples() on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I am trying to convert a simple pandas dataframe into a nested JSON file based on the answer I found here:  [pandas groupby to nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374062/pandas-groupby-to-nested-json)

My grouped dataframe looks like this:

```
                  firstname lastname  orgname         phone        mobile  email
teamname members                                                           
1        0            John      Doe     Anon  916-555-1234          none   john.doe@wildlife.net 
         1            Jane      Doe     Anon  916-555-4321  916-555-7890   jane.doe@wildlife.net
2        0          Mickey    Moose  Moosers  916-555-0000  916-555-1111   mickey.moose@wildlife.net
         1           Minny    Moose  Moosers  916-555-2222          none   minny.moose@wildlife.net
```

My code is:

```
data = pandas.read_excel(inputExcel, sheetname = 'Sheet1', encoding = 'utf8')
grouped = data.groupby(['teamname', 'members']).first()

results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for index, value in grouped.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(index):
        if i ==0:
            nested = results[key]
        elif i == len(index) -1:
            nested[key] = value
        else:
            nested = nested[key]

print json.dumps(results, indent = 4)
```

I get the following error on the first "for" loop.  What causes this error in this circumstance and what would it take to fix it to output the nested json?

```
    for index, value in grouped.itertuples():
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`itertuples()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), the index is included as part of the tuple, so the `for index, value in grouped.itertuples():` doesn't really make sense.  In fact, `itertuples()` uses [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with `Index` being one of the names.

Consider the following setup:

```
data = {'A': list('aabbc'), 'B': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'C': list('vwxyz'), 'D': range(5,10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

Yielding the following DataFrame:

```
     C  D
A B      
a 0  v  5
  1  w  6
b 0  x  7
  1  y  8
c 0  z  9
```

Then printing each tuple in `df.itertuples()` yields:

```
Pandas(Index=('a', 0), C='v', D=5)
Pandas(Index=('a', 1), C='w', D=6)
Pandas(Index=('b', 0), C='x', D=7)
Pandas(Index=('b', 1), C='y', D=8)
Pandas(Index=('c', 0), C='z', D=9)
```

So, what you'll probably want to do is something like the code below, with `value` being replaced by `t[1:]`:

```
for t in grouped.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(t.Index):
        ...
```

If you want to access components of the `namedtuple`, you can access things positionally, or by name. So, in the case of your DataFrame, `t[1]` and `t.firstname` should be equivalent.  Just remember that `t[0]` is the index, so your first column starts at `1`.

Comment: If I run those 2 lines, I get:    for i, key in enumerate(t.index):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Index should be capitalized: `enumerate(t.Index)`.

Comment: That gives me a different error:  for i, key in enumerate(t.Index):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Index'

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using (see `pd.__version__`)? If it's an older version,  `itertuples` may not be implemented as `namedtuple` yet, so trying to access it by name might not work. Trying calling it positionally: `enumerate(t[0])`.  If that doesn't work, try looking at a few of the tuples that are generated by `itertuples` to see what it's actually producing for you, and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: I was using pandas 0.16.1 so I upgraded to 0.18.1 and it seems to have worked (after I updated references to "index" to "t.Index" and "values"
 to "t".   Your help got me to 99% of what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: This is my final code  `data = pandas.read_excel(inputExcel, sheetname = 'SCAT Teams', encoding = 'utf8')

grouped = data.groupby(['teamname', 'members']).first()
print grouped

results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for t in grouped.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(t.Index):
        if i ==0:
            nested = results[key]
        elif i == len(t.Index) -1:
            nested[key] = t
        else:
            nested = nested[key]
            


jsonOutput = json.dumps(results, indent = 4)`

Comment: Would you be willing to chat to explain how this bit of code works?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand itertuples, it will return a tuple with the first value being the index and the remaining values being all of the columns.  You only have for `index, value in grouped.itertuples()` which means it's trying to unpack all of the columns into a single variable, which won't work.  The `groupby` probably comes into play as well but it should still contain all the values within the result which means you still have too many columns being unpacked.