# Easiest way to split JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, formatting, format

I am working on an interactive visualization of the world happiness report from the years 2015 up to 2020. The data was split into 6 csv files. Using pandas, I have succesfully cleaned the data and concatenated  them into one big JSON file with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "Switzerland",
    "Year": 2015,
    "Happiness Rank": 1,
    "Happiness Score": 7.587000000000001,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "Year": 2015,
    "Happiness Rank": 2,
    "Happiness Score": 7.561,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Switzerland",
    "Year": 2016,
    "Happiness Rank": 2,
    "Happiness Score": 7.5089999999999995,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "Year": 2016,
    "Happiness Rank": 3,
    "Happiness Score": 7.501,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Switzerland",
    "Year": 2017,
    "Happiness Rank": 3,
    "Happiness Score": 7.49399995803833,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Iceland",
    "Year": 2017,
    "Happiness Rank": 1,
    "Happiness Score": 7.801,
  }
]
```

Now, I would like to programmatically format the JSON file such that it has the following format:

```
{
    "2015": {
        "Switzerland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 1,
            "Happiness Score": 7.587000000000001
        },
        "Iceland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 2,
            "Happiness Score": 7.561
        }
    },
    "2016": {
        "Switzerland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 2,
            "Happiness Score": 7.5089999999999995
        },
        "Iceland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 3,
            "Happiness Score": 7.501
        }
    },
    "2017": {
        "Switzerland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 3,
            "Happiness Score": 7.49399995803833
        },
        "Iceland": {
            "Happiness Rank": 1,
            "Happiness Score": 7.801
        }
    }
}
```

It has to be done programmatically, since there are over 900 distinct (country, year) pairs. I want the JSON in this format since it make the JSON file more readable, and makes it easier to select appropriate data. If I want the rank of Iceland in 2015, I can then do `data[2015]["Iceland"]["Happiness Rank"]`

Does anyone know the easiest / most convenient way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` is your original list of dictionaries:

```
def by_year(data):
    from itertools import groupby
    from operator import itemgetter

    retain_keys = ("Happiness Rank", "Happiness Score")

    for year, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter("Year")):
        as_tpl = tuple(group)
        yield str(year), dict(zip(map(itemgetter("Country"), as_tpl), [{k: d[k] for k in retain_keys} for d in as_tpl]))


print(dict(by_year(data)))
```

Output:

```
{'2015': {'Switzerland': {'Happiness Rank': 1, 'Happiness Score': 7.587000000000001}, 'Iceland': {'Happiness Rank': 2, 'Happiness Score': 7.561}}, '2016': {'Switzerland': {'Happiness Rank': 2, 'Happiness Score': 7.5089999999999995}, 'Iceland': {'Happiness Rank': 3, 'Happiness Score': 7.501}}, '2017': {'Switzerland': {'Happiness Rank': 3, 'Happiness Score': 7.49399995803833}, 'Iceland': {'Happiness Rank': 1, 'Happiness Score': 7.801}}}
>>>
```

This assumes that the dictionaries in `data` will already be grouped together by year.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the original pandas dataframe from which this JSON was created. With pandas, you can do `df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Country'])`. You can then follow the procedure in [pandas groupby to nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374062/pandas-groupby-to-nested-json) to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you might find `groupby` from the itertools module useful. I was able to do this with

```
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x["Year"])
newdict = {str(year): {entry["Country"]:entry for entry in group} for year, group in groups}
```

Where `data` is the data with the form of the example you gave

It will retain the original fields in the dict, but it can easily be deleted in this way

```
for countries in newdict.values():
    for c in countries.values():
        del c["Year"]
        del c["Country"]
```